# How does linq lambdas work inside a loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, lambda

I'm trying to implement Tasks in my Application.

Here's the sample code:

There's one simple Interface I, 3 classes are derived form it (A,B,C)
I create a list of Is, poplualte it with A, B, C instances, and then create a task for each other to call method do1();

```
  interface I
    {
        void do1();

    }

    class A : I
    {
        public void do1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }


    class B : I
    {
        public void do1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }


    class C : I
    {
        public void do1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<I> l = new List<I>();
            l.Add(new A());
            l.Add(new B());
            l.Add(new C());


            var TaskPool = new List<Task>();


            foreach (var i in l)
            {
                Task task = new Task( () => i.do1()

                    );
                TaskPool.Add(task);
            }


            foreach (var c in TaskPool)
            {
                c.Start();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.Read();
        }


    }
```

I'm expecting to see

```
A
B
C
```

In the output, but instead of it I get

```
C
C
C
```

I kinda found the problem in debugger: All tasks have the same delegate, but I do not know why and how to workaround this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very common question. It relates to how "captured variables" work; short version, you need this:

```
foreach (var i in l)
{
    var copy = i;
    Task task = new Task( () => copy.do1());
    TaskPool.Add(task);
}
```

The problem here is that `i` (from the `foreach`) is *technically* declared **outside** the scope of the loop, and thus is captured at that *outer* scope; you capture the same *variable* each time (C# captures *variables*, not *values). Adding `copy` *inside* the loop-scope changes this; because of the scope, `copy` is captured separately *per iteration*.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. Is 'copy' really a copy? As far as i can see, it's just another reference, wright?

Comment: @portland: It's a copy of the *value of `i`*, whatever that value is... whether it's a reference or a value type value.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you capture the loop variable `i` when assigning the delegates. If you create a temporary copy before the assignment you can avoid capturing the variable and thus get the values you need.

```
foreach (var i in l)
{
    var local = i;
    Task task = new Task( () => local.do1());
    TaskPool.Add(task);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the intended behavior for linq expressions. It is somewhat called variable capturing. Refer to [this link](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2008/03/29/linq-range-odd) for some good detailed information on this topic.

In your case, just replace the linq expression with a method group. I mean:
this...

```
Task task = new Task(i.do1);
```

instead of this...

```
Task task = new Task(() => i.do1());
```

**EDIT:** And one more VERY important thing. You have added the items to the list by adding A, B, C (in that particular order). That does not guarantee that A task will run before B task and so on. You can get anything as the output, ABC, ACB and so on.

Comment: +1 Not a very good explanation - but the solution is elegant and it works :)

Comment: Still very hard to see the difference, according to Marc Gravell♦'s comment

Comment: The link I provided has some good information on the topic. I thought the writer explains it in a much better fashion than I can.